# Append changing number before div data

Tags: javascript

I have this html line:

```
<div class = "upperTextContainer">
 <p id="counterUpperText" class="upperText">Seconds</p>
</div>
```

What if I want to append a changing variable like a number counter before `Seconds` like 9 Seconds... 8 Seconds... etc for instance?

I have tried this with no success:

```js
timeleft = 14;
let savedTimer = setInterval(function(){
  console.log(timeleft)
  counterUpperText.innerHTML += timeleft;
  timeleft--;
  if(timeleft <= 0){
    clearInterval(savedTimer);
    console.log("done");
    return;
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class = "upperTextContainer">
 <p id="counterUpperText" class="upperTexts"> Seconds</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I hope you will not use this kind of code for a precision time count

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not `+=` thats all.

```js
timeleft = 14;
let savedTimer = setInterval(function(){
  console.log(timeleft)
  counterUpperText.innerHTML = `${timeleft}secs`;
  timeleft--;
  if(timeleft <= 0){
    clearInterval(savedTimer);
    console.log("done");
    return;
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class = "upperTextContainer">
 <p id="counterUpperText" class="upperTexts"> Seconds</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, instead of appending to the element content, you need to replace its content.

To do so, you can either

1. replace the complete content of the target element

   ```
   counterUpperText.innerHTML = ""+timeleft+" seconds"
   ```
2. use a new `<span>` element for just the number inside the target element, the new span would become the new target for the counter

   ```
   <p class="upperText"><span id="counterUpperText">99</span> Seconds</p>
   ```

   the new span would become the new target for the counter

   ```
   counterUpperText.innerHTML = timeleft
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Now you are adding the seconds to the html element like this `14131211` by using `+= timeleft`. You should just assign the timeleft to the innerHTML, the following should work.

```js
let timeLeft = 14;
const interval = setInterval(() => {
    document.querySelector('.upperTexts').innerHTML = `${timeLeft--} seconds`;
    timeLeft <= 0 && clearInterval(interval);
}, 1000);
```